# More lazy vs lazier

Tags: meaning, grammar

Can I use *more lazy* instead of *lazier*

If yes, How can I use it?

Comment: Yes, you can. *I'm more lazy than you*.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can say "more lazy"; the trend didn't start just recently, since at least from the beginning of the 1800's there has been a minority writting "more lazy": [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lazier%2Cmore+lazy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clazier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20lazy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clazier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20lazy%3B%2Cc0). It can be noticed from the ngram, however, that "lazier" is not on the way out and that as the frequency of "lazier" falls, that of "more lazy" does too.

You might use it in such a case as found in this page from [Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lazier-more-lazy.2395552/).

- People are starting to get lazier and figuring out ways to be more lazy.

You might think that to avoid the repetition adds something to your sentence. I personnally can't see any difference or improvement. It seems for instance, that shifting sentence stress from the last "lazier" to "figure out" blanks out the identification of the same state that should be found in the term of the end if that term is "more lazy" and in that case I would say that "lazier" is not to be replaced by "more lazy"; this, however is possibly a question of opinion.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.